# Google Drive Sharing title "Quickstart Uploaded File " is coming in ios

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, file-sharing

When I upload/share an image on Google drive using ios SDK then image name becomes "Quickstart Uploaded File".png.

I want to change the name of image. How would it be possible?
Please help me I am a beginner in ios.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I solved this issue.
I was using GTL library so I add the description title.

 GTLDriveFile *file = [GTLDriveFile object];
 file.title = @"Your choice";

Thanks